# How to get the first and last date of the month with Year and Month in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code , from the month and year,  need 1st and last date of the month

for ex month =3 and year= 2022

first_date = 2021-03-01 00:00:00

last_date = 2021-03-31 00:00:00

I tried with calendar but it simply returns (1 ,31)

```
import calendar

month =3
year= 2022
print( calendar.monthrange(2002, 1))
```

Comment: You probably want to use the variables you've defined (`month` and `year`) instead of printing the range of a different month and year. You're getting back the lowest and highest day number of the month specified, so you just have to convert these to `datetime` objects now (using `datetime.datetime(year, month, day)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From monthrange() you will get the first day and the number of days in that month. You can use the datetime method to convert it to date.

```
month =3
year= 2022
first, last = calendar.monthrange(year, month)
print(first, last)

print(datetime.datetime(year, month, 1))
print(datetime.datetime(year, month, last))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own function to calculate the last day of the month:

```
def last_day_of_month(date):
    if date.month == 12:
        return date.replace(day=31)
    return date.replace(month=date.month+1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

So:

```
>>> last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2021, 3, 19))
datetime.date(2021, 3, 31)
```

Similarly, we can use a one-liner for the first date:

```
(dt.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)
```

So:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 19)
print((dt.replace(day=1) + datetime.timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1))
>>> 2021-03-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using `datetime` module

```
import datetime

def get_last_day_of_month(day):
    next_month = day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)
```

the output will be:

```
for month in range(1, 13):
    print(get_last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2020, month, 1)))

    
2020-01-31
2020-02-29
2020-03-31
2020-04-30
2020-05-31
2020-06-30
2020-07-31
2020-08-31
2020-09-30
2020-10-31
2020-11-30
2020-12-31
```

for the first day you can just put the day always 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dateutil` library to accomplish this as well.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

month = 3
year = 2022
first = date(year, month, 1)
last = first + relativedelta(day=31)
```